# Enterprise library 4.1 logging error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, enterprise-library

I am using Enterprise library 4.1 logging. I am getting compile error at 'EnterpriseLibraryContainer'. EnterpriseLibraryContainer doesn't work for 4.1 version?

```
public LogWriter defaultWriter;

public Logging()
{
    // Resolve the default LogWriter object from the container.
    // The actual concrete type is determined by the configuration settings.
    defaultWriter = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<LogWriter>();
}

[Description("Logging to EverViewer and RollingFile with Write method of a LogWriter")]
public void LogWriter(string message, string title, EventLogEntryType eventType)
{
    // Check if logging is enabled before creating log entries.
    if (defaultWriter.IsLoggingEnabled())
    {
        // Create a string array (or List<>) containing the categories.
        string[] logCategories = new string[] { "General" };

        LogEntry logEntry = new LogEntry();
        logEntry.Message = message;
        logEntry.Categories = logCategories;
        logEntry.Priority = 10;
        logEntry.EventId = 9005;
        logEntry.Severity = ConvertEventType(eventType);
        logEntry.Title = title;
        defaultWriter.Write(logEntry);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EnterpriseLibraryContainer` was introduced with Enterprise Library 5 so is not available with Enterprise Library 4.1.

Try replacing that code with the following to get the default writer:

```
public Logging()
{
    // Resolve the default LogWriter object from the container.
    // The actual concrete type is determined by the configuration settings.
    defaultWriter = new LogWriterFactory().Create();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you by any chance targeting the .NET 4 Client Profile instead of the full .NET 4?